# Common name for an award given by students

Tags: academic-life, awards

How would you call an award given by students to their favourite professor/instructor by voting? *"Favourite professor award"*? Any other suggestions?

This is not about how a new award should be named, but about how to properly identify this type of award in, say, one's CV.

The students gave the award a particular name ('mandarine award') but, finally, the medal they prepared had the inscription 'Best Teacher [of a given degree]'.

Comment: "Favourite" in what sense? Best in teaching, or something else?

Comment: @GoodDeeds 'Favourite' in general —A mix between good teaching and rapport.

Comment: Why are you asking? Are you wondering how to list this on something like a CV?

Comment: @BryanKrause, yes, that's the motivation. But I also think it can be helpful to other people.

Comment: Well, it changes the answers considerably. If you're creating a new award and trying to decide on a name, then you want suggestions for what an award should be called. If you've received an award and want to list it on your CV, you're looking not for what the award *should* be called but rather about how it's appropriate to list it on your CV. Those are two very different questions. You don't get to claim on your CV the award that someone else thinks your award should be named, you get to claim the award you actually received.

Comment: @BryanKrause OK, I see. I edited my question again.

Comment: On CV I would use the name of the award, and when the name is not descriptive, I would add a short description. For example "Mandarine Award, University of XYZ, 2025. Awarded annually by students to the instructor which is most bla bla bla".

Comment: @NickS I partially agree. Maybe this would be OK for a full-length CV, but I am rather thinking of a short-version CV (for a webpage, for instance). What do you think about the answer I provided below?

Comment: @Vicent To me, changing the names of awards by nicer sounding names should be a NO in academia. And for a webpage, one can typically just link a webpage with details about the award, under the name.

Comment: @NickS, not because of nicer names, but for a better understanding. It is actually the 'best teacher' award, as they say in the medal. The particular name is 'mandarine' as a reference to orange and lemon awards, which are sometimes used for the most popular and disgusting person of a given profession, respectively. It could be also 'More popular professor'. Anyway, the name of 'mandarine' could change in future editions, but the idea would be the same. There are no other 'best professor' awards in this School, I mean.

Comment: @Vicent "Mandarine Award ('Best Teacher of Basket-Weaving', by student vote)" is quite short and descriptive and safely not misleading, and the extra characters will both have near zero cost in website bandwidth and fit easily in a single line of a printed CV.

Comment: The issue is that some universities have "Best Teacher Award," which is often/typically a University-wide award.  I would be surprised if your university does not have such an award.

Comment: @BryanKrause Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: It doesn't address the question asked, so no.

Answer (score 1):

My former institute has a "Teacher Talent Award" for junior lecturers, the teachers are nominated by Faculty Student Councils. A name like this may make clear that there might be a distinction between popular, nice, and *good/talented* professors. If that would be something you'd like.

My former institute also has an award named after a former rector magnificus for senior teachers, for that prize they use student evaluations (as well as some other metrics), not direct voting. Still, using the name of a former professor that was exceptional at your institute might be a nice idea.

Answer (score -2):

Given the extra context provided, what about this?

*"Best Teacher students award"*

as in "Best Actor Academy Award".